# ImageMagick convert command not generating images

Tags: centos, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to extract images in CentOS machine using ImageMagick's convert command as below:

```
convert -coalesce http://cdn.abcdf.com/p/f7/81/d3/40/f781d34031e68828eaasdwc937cf3f8.gif /mnt/temp/123.png
```

I am getting the following error:

```
convert: unable to open image `//cdn.adnxs.com/p/f7/81/d3/40/f781d34031e6882840eaa6dc937cf3f8.gif': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `HTTP' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: no images defined `/mnt/ephemeral2/creative_report/temp/123.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258
```

I tried reinstalling ImageMagick from source but it was of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by reinstalling IM and the missing libxml2-devel library. Below are the steps I followed:

```
1)cd (ImageMagick folder)
2)make uninstall
3)yum install tcl-devel libpng-devel libjpeg-devel ghostscript-devel bzip2-devel freetype-devel libtiff-devel libxml2-devel
4)wget ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.9-0.tar.gz
5)tar xvfz ImageMagick-6.9.9-0.tar.gz
6)cd (the folder created)
7)./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-bzlib=yes --with-fontconfig=yes --with-freetype=yes --with-gslib=yes --with-gvc=yes --with-jpeg=yes --with-jp2=yes --with-png=yes --with-tiff=yes
8)make clean
9)make
10)make install
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows I would put double quotes around the path as it looks like it is breaking up the image path.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is bad. My browser tells me it cannot find the server. In ImageMagick, you should read the input image first. So if you fix your URL, then

```
convert http://cdn.abcdf.com/p/f7/81/d3/40/f781d34031e68828eaasdwc937cf3f8.gif -coalesce /mnt/temp/123.png
```

Comment: frmw42 I tried reading input image first as you suggested. I am still getting same errors.

Comment: Try the following, which accesses the Wikipedia globe image: `convert https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png image.png` That works for me on IM 6.9.6.5 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra. If that does not work, then check your policy.xml file to see if HTTPS read is disabled. That may be a security prevention on your system.